# how to handle slow jQuery addClass effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a pagination list of page numbers for users to select the page. When a user clicks any page it will run the ajax request first and then load the data to render the page. Then the `jQuery.addClass` is run to show which page number is currently active, by adding the 'active' class - `addClass('active')`.

The problem is the `jQuery.addClass` effect works sometimes but not everytime (`addClass` just doesn't add the class to the selected element). I think this is because the DOM is loaded too fast and jQuery can't catch up. Even when I use `setTimeout` it still doesn't work sometimes. How can I handle it?

```
$(() => {

    //Moving page number and
    //Set Active for moving page number
    $(document).on("click", "a.btn-pagination", function(event){
        $('#page_loading').css('display', ''); //--> display the page loading gif
        var num = $(this).attr('data-page');

        $('#result_container').load(base_url+'store/movePage/'
        + $(this).attr('data-page'));

        setTimeout( () => {
            updateButton();
            $('.btn-pagination[data-page = ' + num + ']').show().addClass('active');
        }, 300);

        setTimeout( () => {
            $('#page_loading').css('display', 'none'); //--> hide the page loading gif
        }, 400);
    });

});

function updateButton(){
    let dateValue = $('#currentdate').text().trim();


    if(dateValue >= maxdt){
        $('#next_btn').html('<a class="btn-disable" style="color: gray;">Newer <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>');
    }
    else {
        $('#next_btn').html('<a href="#" onclick="nextDate()">Newer <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>');
    }

    if(dateValue <= mindt){
        $('#previous_btn').html('<a class="btn-disable" style="color: gray;"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Older</a>');
    }
    else {
        $('#previous_btn').html('<a href="#" onclick="prevDate()"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Older</a>');
    }
}
```

Comment: use the `complete` callback for the jquery `load` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use **callbacks when using async operations**, as they provide certainty that the callback won't run until the async operation has finished.

Instead of this,

```
$('#result_container').load(base_url+'store/movePage/'
        + $(this).attr('data-page'));
```

use a callback as part of your load

```
$('#result_container').load(base_url+'store/movePage/'
        + $(this).attr('data-page'), function(){
  updateButton();
  $('.btn-pagination[data-page = ' + num + ']').show().addClass('active');
});
```

Then remove this:

```
            updateButton();
            $('.btn-pagination[data-page = ' + num + ']').show().addClass('active');
        }, 300);
```